# setting an array in variable yaml

Tags: arrays, variables, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have been trying to set up an array in yaml pipeline variable. So usually when I want to create a yaml variable in script, I do [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash):

```
- bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar]hello world"
```

However, the issue is I need the variable as an array so that I can map through later. And I have this but it does not work:

```
- bash: |
    myArray=($(get-array command))
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVar]$myArray"
```

it throws an error that `Expected at least one key-value pair in the mapping`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: You can't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57174843/can-an-array-variable-defined-in-azure-devops-variable-group

Comment: Read https://www.w3schools.io/file/yaml-arrays/, it might help

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483194/pass-array-of-files-into-the-parameter-of-awscli1-task/67498247#67498247

Answer (score 1):

The variables are treated as strings in Azure Pipelines. Array is not supported: [Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

[image]